# Extremely simple git/Github use case of merging simple 1 commit branch causes branch deletion failure

Tags: git, github

Let me preface my question by stating that git is the most confusing thing I've ever worked with in 25 years. For some reason, I have a mental block that really prevents me from understanding it.

I have a 'master' branch both locally and in Github.

I created a local branch called 'admin_tweaks'.

I checked out 'admin_tweaks'.

I made some changes.

I pushed the branch to origin.

I created a Pull Request on github.

Github stated that there were no conflicts and the merge to master could be done automatically. So I pressed the button.

Github gave me this message:

```
Pull request successfully merged and closed
You’re all set—the admin_tweaks branch can be safely deleted.
```

Locally, I checked out the master branch. I did a `git pull`.

I saw my changes come down.

I tried to delete the 'admin_tweaks' branch locally with:

```
git branch -d admin_tweaks
```

and received this very confusing and concerning message:

```
warning: not deleting branch 'admin_tweaks' that is not yet merged to
     'refs/remotes/origin/admin_tweaks', even though it is merged to HEAD.
error: The branch 'admin_tweaks' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D admin_tweaks'.
```

What part of a healthy workflow am I missing here? I have absolutely zero confidence that my changes are merged properly.

Comment: can you add this to your question? `git branch -a --contains admin_tweaks`. Also `git status`.

Comment: Side notes: (1) Don't worry: Git is complicated, and often poorly-explained. (2) I recommend avoiding `git pull`. It merely runs two Git commands for you, and is intended as a convenience, but it turns out to be inconvenient a significant fraction of the time. It gets in the way of understanding Git. Avoid it and you'll be (slightly) happier and will "get" Git faster.

Comment: Main question: you mention `admin_tweaks` and show the name `admin_tweaks` a few times, but your text quoted from GitHub says `inquisitor_tweaks`. Which name is wrong, or are all of these correct?

Comment: I'm wondering if the merge by github was not performed with a ff or merge but a rebase, perhaps?

Comment: I used the first option in the Github list. Rebase was the 3rd option. The options were "Create a Merge Commit", "Squash and Merge", and "Rebase and Merge".

Comment: @torek that was the second one I tried, I pulled the message from the wrong screen. Corrected.

Comment: @torek I appreciate  what you say about git and I'm doing some online classes now to get some visuals. I've done "git pull" for so long but now that I'm beginning to work with branches it looks like I need to do "git fetch". Will fetch automatically update my local tree with non-conflicting changes?

Comment: Which branch were you on when you pulled?

Comment: `git fetch` (with no additional arguments) means "contact the other Git" (assuming there's just one other Git) "and get all of their latest work and update all my `origin/*` names so that I know about their latest commits". It does no *merging* at alll, it just updates these `origin/*` names. That's the first half of incorporating someone else's (upstream) work. That's why `git pull` runs a second command; the problem is, until you have the actual commits, you don't necessarily want to pick a second command yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message normally means your local `admin_tweaks` is not fully merged into `origin/admin_tweaks` or seems not to be. I get this message sometimes when I merge a branch into master. It is not a sign of a problem: the message confirms that you branch was merged into HEAD, which means your pull request worked as expected.

Doing

```
git log --decorate --graph
```

should show you why Git thinks `admin_tweaks` is not merged into `origin/admin_tweaks`. It could be due to `origin/admin_tweaks` being deleted when the pull request was accepted on GitHub, for example.

Comment: My favourite `git log` variant is `git log  --color --decorate --graph --format="%Cred%ad %Cgreen%h %Cblue%an%Cred%d %Creset%s"  --date=short --date-order`, which I have save as alias `git logs`. I also have the same with `--all` added, aliased as `git loga`.

Comment: If you run `git config --global core.abbrev 9`, my `git logs` and `git loga` give a really nice concise one-commit-per-line view.

Comment: @joanis: modern Git will abbreviate to the "right number" automatically, if you leave out the specific value. Some Git repositories are small enough to get away with about 5 or 6, some (Linux kernel) are large enough to need 10 to 12, so fixing the number at 9 is not necessarily a good idea. Other than that, making some aliases for useful variants of `git log` *is* a really good idea.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the hint. I just took out my core.abbrev config and it dropped to 7 in my current project. I set that up back when it was not automatic yet...